# File.Create and ghost file

Tags: c#, windows, file, process, stream

I have the code like this:

```
string[] paths = { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Test", folder };
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(paths);

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

path += "\\";

string p=path+"test.txt";
try
{
    FileStream file = File.Create(p);
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file);
    tw.WriteLine("Test: " + 1);
    tw.Close();
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I have the test1:

```
private void OpenStream(string p)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(p, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s.ReadToEnd(), "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

And the test2:

```
private void OpenF(string p)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(p);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Everywhere this code works fine, but one user has result:

Test1: OK, message with the text appears,

Test2: Message appears with information that file doesn't exist. I can't find file in this location, and even specific parts of directory "Test", folder, don't appear.

So all in all, stream can read text from the file which doesn't exist. How is this possible? How to prevent this situation?

This problem is only with location Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData.

Comment: It may be a permission issue.  If you run the .exe as Administrator, 'Test1' will have admin privileges, but 'Test2' may not since it is starting a new process

Comment: I thought about permissions, but the directory /Test/folder/ doesn't exist. This is so strange. This problem is only with location Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I create a file in SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData (in my case "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\") the file in fact is created in other subdirectory instead (in my case "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Packages\F0C6F5FC-4B4B-478D-958D-BAD69252637E_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalCache\Local") I found the file doing a recursive search from LocalApplicationData with the file explorer....